# Multi-part specification SQL error

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio, data-views

I am trying to pull bounce information for subscribers of a particular data extension using the following SQL:

```
Select 
o.JobID,
o.SubscriberKey,
o.EventDate,
o.BounceCategory,
o.SMTPCode,
o.SMTPBounceReason,
o.ListID,
s.ListName
s.Email address
from [_bounce] o
INNER JOIN 'ent.EDU SPIRIT DATA COMBINED' s
    ON o.SubscriberKey=s.Email address
```

I am receiving a multi-part specification error saying it's not allowed.

Can anyone shed any light on why please?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your single quotes surrounding the Data Extension name with square brackets. Any field or data extension name that contains a space should be surrounded with brackets.

```
Select 
o.JobID,
o.SubscriberKey,
o.EventDate,
o.BounceCategory,
o.SMTPCode,
o.SMTPBounceReason,
o.ListID,
s.ListName,
s.[Email address]
from [_bounce] o
INNER JOIN ent.[EDU SPIRIT DATA COMBINED] s
  ON o.SubscriberKey = s.[Email address]
```

Comment: I believe double quotes can also be used `"` in this way.  e.g. `s."Email address"`

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington, I have deduced that it is because the data extension name contains spaces and for some reason it doesn't work when you join with a data view.